# Downloading File With JavasScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I am trying to download files which i am selecting from a table from a directory in my computer.

I am displaying all files in a directory at a table. I can select this files from table and get their directories.

Now i am trying to download this files to different directory in my computer.

Is it possible to someone give me a lead about this manner.

Comment: possible with javascript

Comment: To server files you need a `http server`.

Comment: Well, all this talk of "is it possible" may be making some assumptions.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  What's the user experience you're looking to achieve?  If you want your web page to silently fetch files from the internet and save them to the local file system without user interaction then I'm afraid that can't be done without some sort of browser plugin.  JavaScript alone can't read/write the local file system.

Comment: i'm still searching on internet but i couldnt find a solution which i can use when i try it with javascript chrome gives me error as "Not allowed to load local resource:"

Comment: thank you david. For now i'm trying to download a file from a directory to a directory on my computer. user experience will follow that later.

Comment: @sureshmanda Sorry, this is not the right place to tell you... but you need to know. Please stop making edits where you change capital I to lowercase i. Why do you do this? This is capitalized in English. If English is not your native language, it might be better to stick to code/formatting edits which you do a good job with.